# How to instal my application in client system when I am using server explorer without connection string

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, database-connection, server-explorer

I have added a Linq to Sql class and In server explore I have attached my sql server name and database in my system. A connection string has created automatically in app.Config file. I am not writing any connection string anywhere except that. I am creating DataContext class object and using the data from my database.

DataContext Class

```
 DtContext.purchasesDtlsDataContext purchasesDC = new slsandPchsLib.DtContext.purchasesDtlsDataContext();
```

retrieving data from database

```
 var goods = from gds in purchasesDC.goodsrcpts_rd(Id) select gds;
 var goodsDtls = from dtls in purchasesDC.goodsrcptsdtls_rd(Id) select dtls;
```

As this I am doing well in my computer. Now I am try ing to use my application in another(client) computer. I have attached my database to  sqlServer and changed server name in App.Config file DataSource. Still I am not able to connect to database. I am getting an error as

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

How can I solve my problem

my connection string in app.config is ....

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="slsandPchsLib.Properties.Settings.SalesPrchsConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=CENSYS07\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SalesPrchs;Integrated Security=True"          
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error has caused because your tables in `dbml` file are from different database and your `connection string` in `app.config` belongs to different database.

Kindly check with your database belongingness with your `connection string in app.config file`.

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

As you might know this error occures because system does not be able to find your database name which you have mentioned in app.config.

Comment: No sir.. I have added the same database and changed the connection string.. still I am getting the same problem

Comment: Your database exist on same machine or on different machine?

Comment: will you please paste your connection string?

Comment: Is there any username password to your database?

Comment: problem is that your computer is not able to find database 'SalesPrchs' in the system.

Comment: are you sure [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="SalesPrchs")] in dbml?

Comment: where should write that string in dbml class

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26763/discussion-between-naresh-jadapalli-and-freelancer)